# IntelliJ ultimate doesn't find web application support in existing project

Tags: intellij-idea, web.xml

Hi I've got IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2.2 and can't add Web app development support to existing project... 
I tried [the suggestion on the IJ doc site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/enabling-web-application-support.html?search=web%20application%20support), but in the `Add framework support` windows there's nothing like `Web application`, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: AddFrameworkSupport issue]

However, if i start new project `Web application support` is available.

Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It might be that your application has already been recognized as an web-app, hence the option is no longer displayed. If you go to `File` -> `Project structure` -> `Facets` can you see the `Web` facet there? If it's not present, can you click on the green plus and add it?

Comment: Yes, it's there. So what can i do?

Comment: That means your app is already set-upas a web app. Now you need to click on the `Web` and adjust its configuration to match your project (if it's not already ok), and that's about it.